# Function to use globaMap inside tHMap

Tags: talend

[image]

I've been trying out some examples on talend ETL's `tHMap` component and started with different `Functions` available in `Mapping` perspective for creating new data mappers.

**Question :** 
Is there any way to evaluate expressions like `globalMap.get("myVar")` inside tHMap under the value tab for any given element, like the way we can do in `tMap` or `tXMLMap` ?